# pandas taking entries in column order

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have this df1:

```
ID  Name    Alias   Nickname
101 Robert  Rob Bob
201 Tom     
315     Megan   Meg
405 Teddy       Ted
510         Bill
602
```

But I want to add in a Result column that take the entries in an order (Name, Alias (if Name is empty), Nickname (if Alias and Name both empty))

```
ID  Name    Alias   Nickname    Result
101 Robert  Rob Bob Robert
201 Tom         Tom
315     Megan   Meg Megan
405 Teddy       Ted Teddy
510         Bill    Bill
602             NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
df1['Result'] = df1[['Name', 'Alias', 'Nickname']].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]

Out [142]:    

    ID      Name    Alias   Nickname    Result
0   101     Robert  Rob     Bob         Robert
1   201     Tom     NaN     NaN         Tom
2   315     Megan   Meg     NaN         Megan
3   405     Teddy   Ted     NaN         Teddy
4   510     Bill    NaN     NaN         Bill
5   602     NaN     NaN     NaN         NaN
```